# Stop a user from circumventing IP block?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, ip-blocking, x-forwarded-for

A user is somehow avoiding an IP block in apache 2.2/2.4, and I can not figure out how. The company I work for hosts hundreds of sites in different datacenters; this user is attacking several of the sites we host.

Depending on the datacenter, the user with comes in with their IP in the `remote_addr` or `X-Forwarded-For` fields. We maintain two lists of "bad actors" which are in a file based on their IP address in either the remote_addr or X-Forwarded_For fields, and this file is included in the `apache.conf`. The lines either look like 
`SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 41\.216\.xxx\.xxx BlockedBot`
or `SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 41\.216\.xxx\.xxx BlockedBot`. We then have the following in our apache.conf, near the bottom:

```
<Location />
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        AuthType none
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from env=BlockedBot
        Deny from env=EmptyHost
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require not env BlockedBot
            Require not env EmptyHost
        </RequireAll>
    </IfVersion>
</Location>
```

My problem is, after putting this bad actor's ip in both files, making sure they were both included, his requests still come through fine.  To double check, I used curl with the bad actor's IP in the X-Forwarded-For field, and it correctly blocks my request:

`curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 41.216.xxx.xxx" www.testexample.com/images/fpo/check-14aca5cd1a.png`

The bad actor issuing the same exact request with his IP in the XFF field gets through with a 200 status code, no problem. How is this possible?

Comment: And if it is always the same IP, why do not use the best tool to filter an IP : a firewall ?

Comment: We host hundreds of sites in at least 12 different datacenters, different ones using different hardware. the issue is that this *should* be working to block IPs, it works when I test it, but it doesn't work on the actual bad actor, and I'd like to figure out why.

Comment: How did you configure mod_remoteip?